# Why does a texture affect the hair particles' dinsity differently from a vertex group?

Tags: texturing, particles, hair, vertex-weights

Yesterday I noticed that when I switched from a vertex group to a texture as my density input the distribution of hair changed and I got less hair volume overall. I experimented with it today and I came to this:

1. hair with no influence
2. hair with vertex group influence. VG is a gradient
3. hair with texture influence. Texture is a gradient

[image]

You can clearly see 2 and 3 aren't the same and 3 has much less volume – although I'd say that number 3 is closer to the gradient spread. Still, it's clear that #3 has way less particles than the unmodified version.

Here's the weight paint:

[image]

[image]

Why does it happen? How can I maintain the same distribution weight between the textures and vertex groups?

This is blender 2.91.0

[image]